# firefox not showing login page at airports or shopping malls

Tags: wireless-networking, firefox

I have found that at some airports and shopping malls, Firefox doesn't show the wifi login page. Hence, I can't use their wifi. The page that Firefox displays is the usual warning page that says the connection is insecure with an option of "get me out of here". It doesn't have the "I understand the risk" option to let me use the wifi network.

In such cases, I have to resort to Chrome. I launch Chrome, get the login page, log in, then close Chrome and I am able to use Firefox to surf the net.

I wonder if there is a setting I can set to make Firefox display the login page.

I'm running Firefox 68.4.2 on a Huawei cell phone.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a FireFox issue.

This is a problem with how the captive portal works when you join a public WiFi hotspot.

The problem is, the captive portal intercepts your initial web request in order to display the user agreement or whatever else they want you to do. If your browser is trying to access an “HTTPS” site then it is going to detect the site isn’t secure.

The answer is simple, navigate to an HTTP site. Or change your homepage to an HTTP site. I tell most of my users to go to http://cnn.com. But any non-HTTPS site will work. Simply changing your homepage to http://google.com will probably suffice.

Comment: Google will not work because of HSTS & friends which automatically upgrade the connection. Personally, I use http://example.com/ but I recognize that's not the most memorable site for others.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to wait till the next time I go to an airport or shopping mall to try it.